# Sequentially processing multiple files in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have the following use case: I need to process a big number of files. Each processing looks more or less like this:

1) read file

2) perform operation (a) on the content

3) perform operation (b) on the content

4) perform operation (c) on the content

```
    ...
```

n) delete file

Spring Batch seems like a good solution to this problem with one exception: I don't want to read all the files in step 1), pass all of them to step 2) etc. because it would use up a lot of memory.

**EDIT**: I commit my files to memory (not to the DB). This is why I'd prefer to process the files one by one or in batches. I mean: run all steps on a single file/batch (the file/batch gets removed in the last step, memory gets cleaned up), then proceed to the next file/batch and so on.

Does Spring Batch have a mechanism supporting multiple execution of all steps over and over?
Or should I just run the same job multiple times until I've run out of files?

Thanks and best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple case for N files you need to execute N jobs, each one is passed a file name as `JobParameter`. Each your processing step cannot be expressed in terms of Spring Batch, but you can use `CompositeItemProcessor` to chain your processors.

Comment: Sorry, this question is a little outdated, but what you're writing here is exactly what I eventually did :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

in Spring Batch Doc this is handled under [multi-file input](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#multiFileInput)

it works with one step and what this will do is:

- create list of file locations
- open first file, read/process till end, close file
- open next... and so on

Comment: hmm... Thanks, this will help me a little bit in some cases, but still if I need to run multiple steps, this will cause me to load all my files at once, right?
And this is something I'd like to avoid, not to clutter up my memory.
But thanks for the tip :)

Comment: no the files are handled sequentially and the individual file is not in memory completely, the implementation uses standard java mechanism with file(pointer) and buffered streams, so only the read items * commit-rate are held in memory (e.g. commit-rate 1000, means 1000 read lines, converted to items)

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems I did not explain my case completely. I commit the read file content into memory. This is why I'd prefer to execute all my steps on a single file, then execute all steps on the next file and so on... (because in the last step I remove the file).